# Converting wide data to long when labels need to be manually specified

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'POSTING_AMOUNT1': [10,20,30], 'POSTING_AMOUNT2': [100,200,300],
       'POSTING_AMOUNT3': [15,25,35], 'POSTING_AMOUNT4': [20,40,60]}
```

My expected output needs to be as follows:

| Column | Posting_Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 25 |
| 3 | 35 |
| 4 | 20 |
| 4 | 40 |
| 4 | 60 |

I have tried using the pandas .melt function with no luck. The issue I think is that I am manually trying to assign labels to the 'Column' column. This is what I attempted amongst other tries:

```
melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=[1,2,3,4], value_vars=['POSTING_AMOUNT1', 'POSTING_AMOUNT2', 'POSTING_AMOUNT3',
       'POSTING_AMOUNT4'], var_name='Column', value_name='Posting_Amount')
```

Comment: `pd.melt(df).replace({"variable": {r".*(\d)": r"\1"}}, regex=True)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is with [pandass' wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
(pd.wide_to_long(
    df.reset_index(), 
    i = 'index', 
    stubnames='POSTING_AMOUNT', 
    j = 'column')
.reset_index('column')
)
       column  POSTING_AMOUNT
index                        
0           1              10
1           1              20
2           1              30
0           2             100
1           2             200
2           2             300
0           3              15
1           3              25
2           3              35
0           4              20
1           4              40
2           4              60
```

Another option is with [pyjanitor's pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df.pivot_longer(names_to = ('.value', 'Column'), names_pattern = r"(.+)(\d)")
   Column  POSTING_AMOUNT
0       1              10
1       1              20
2       1              30
3       2             100
4       2             200
5       2             300
6       3              15
7       3              25
8       3              35
9       4              20
10      4              40
11      4              60
```